# Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 Xamarim.Form Emulators

Tags: visual-studio-2015, emulation, xamarin.forms

I just started to play Xamarim in Visual Studio 2015 update 2. I created a brand new cross-platform project `Visual C#` -> `Cross-Platform` -> `Blank App (Xaamrim.Form Portable)`, so I get 6 projects by default.

Without making any code changes I try to run them in emulator:

- iOS -> it looks I must have a Mac to see the emulator, because I got `No remotely accessible Macs were detected on your network.`
- Android project shows nothing when I hit F5. Do I need to install anything else to see the emulator.
- UWP loads fine.
- WinPhone 8.1 failed to load in emulator: `There were deployment errors. Continue?` but in my Error List window there is no single error displayed.

Anybody can tell me what exactly do I need to open each app in emulators?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you need a Mac available in order to build/debug Xamarin.iOS projects. Any Mac on your network will suffice, as long as you have Xamarin installed on it. Most devs run Windows inside of a virtual machine on a Mac, which works well and avoids some of the hassles of dealing with a second physical machine.
2. You need an Android simulator installed. I recommend either the one that comes with Visual Studio 2015 (it might not be installed by default), or the free Xamarin Android Player. The Visual Studio Android Simulator only works if you have Hyper-V enabled in Windows (which is also required by the Windows Phone emulator - so if WinPhone works for you then you should use the VS Android simulator). Xamarin Android Player (XAP) runs *very* slowly when Hyper-V is enabled, but really fast on Mac OSX or in Windows without Hyper-V. So basically, if you need to use the WinPhone emulator then also use Microsoft's VS Android simulator. But if you don't use the WinPhone emulator then go with XAP.
3. Groovy
4. There is also a Deployment Output window in Visual Studio. There might be some clues there about what is going wrong. You probably just didn't install the Windows Phone emulators in Visual Studio setup though. It is right next to the option to install the VS Android simulator.